# Moving the mouse cursor out of VM stops keyboard input in that VM

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am having issues with input in VMware Workstation Player 12 in windowed mode or on multiple screens. When typing something in the VM and moving mouse cursor out of the VM without clicking on anything (for example on the second screen with host OS), the typing in that VM stops until I move the cursor back into VM.

Can this feature be disabled somehow so I am able to type in the virtual machine even when cursor is outside of it?

Both guest and host are Win10 x64 OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically you can, but practically not really.

When you move the mouse cursor out of the guest screen, you're ungrabbing (releasing input) from the VM.  The whole point of moving the mouse cursor out of the VM is to tell it that you no longer wish to direct input to the VM.  Imagine if you could move the mouse cursor out but that the VM still took keyboard input: you'd move the mouse cursor out, click on some other window, start typing, and then keys would go to the VM, not to the window you had just clicked on.  That sounds incredibly confusing. (And if you don't intend to click on another window, then why do you want to move the mouse cursor out of the VM?)

That said, you *could* attach a second USB keyboard to your host and then connect that as a USB device to the VM, and then your VM would have its own dedicated keyboard. (Note that doing this requires setting:

```
usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE"
usb.generic.allowLastHID = "TRUE"
```

in the VM's `.vmx` file first so that USB keyboards and mice are treated like generic USB devices.  See https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1033435 for more details.)

---

Now, maybe you don't actually want to move the mouse cursor out of the VM.  Maybe you just want it to be out of the way and are trying to move it to the corner of the screen, but you're *accidentally* moving it out of the VM.  If that's the case, then in Workstation you can avoid that by going to Edit > Preferences > Input > Cursor and unchecking "Automatically grab and ungrab the mouse".  Player doesn't provide UI to change this preference, but Player uses the same preferences file, so you can manually edit the preferences file (`%APPDATA%\VMware\preferences.ini` on a Windows host, `~/.vmware/preferences` on Linux) by closing all Player instances and adding the line:

```
pref.motionUngrab = "FALSE"
```

---

Or, if you just want keyboard input to automatically go into the guest as long as the VMware Workstation or Player window has focus, regardless of where the mouse is, you can [enable grab-on-keypress](https://superuser.com/a/1113422/210417).  Note, however, that this will automatically move the mouse cursor back into the guest since, from the guest's perspective, it needs to be *somewhere* onscreen.

Comment: Yes the fact is that I always end up accidentally moving mouse out of VM window when typing for example my passwords where I have numeric digits in it, ending up with writing just the part of the password until I move the mouse to get space for my hand to write on NumPad :) Unfortunately, I cannot find mentioned option Edit > Preferences > Input > Cursor in VMware Workstation 12 Player. Maybe it was available in older versions, but in this one it isn't?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you were using Player and not Workstation.  In that case, you'll have to edit the preferences file yourself: Quit Player, open `%APPDATA%\VMware\preferences.ini` in a text editor, and add a line: `pref.motionUngrab = "FALSE"`.

Comment: @IkkieCZ If this answers your question, then you should upvote this answer and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I'd love it if there was the option to be able to move the mouse out of the VMWare window and still have keyboard input directed to the VM, until I clicked on something in the host. This is just how everything else works in Windows, I can type in a window even if I move the mouse away, until I clicked on some other window.

Comment: @gazialankus Can you explain *why* you want to move the mouse cursor out of the guest window?  Note you could have keyboard input automatically go to the VM with the mouse cursor out of the window [if you enable grab-on-keypress](http://superuser.com/a/1113422/210417).

Comment: My second and third sentences above explain why this should be the case in Windows. The other two questions already give a good reason for the user moving the mouse away. And why would I want every key to go to the guest with grab-on-keypress?? If you work for VMWare, please consider this as a feature request. If not, maybe try to be content when you don't have an answer.

Comment: @gazialankus You say "why would I want every key to go to the guest with grab-on-keypress", yet that's the behavior you're asking for. (Note that keys that would be processed by the host window itself would not go to the guest, and keys would go to the guest only if the host window is the active window.) Anyway, mostly I'm curious, because the typical reason is to get the mouse cursor out of the way from where you're typing, but as I mentioned, disabling auto-ungrab would achieve the same effect.

Comment: @jamesdlin Oh, I'm really sorry. earlier today I tried grab-on-keypress with multiple monitors with vmware full screen on one, and I swear it was grabbing keys even after clicking on a window other than vmware. now I have only my laptop, with vmware windowed and it indeed does what I wanted, as you just pointed out. I hope I missed something in the multi-monitor case and I'll be able to keep typing after pushing the mouse away. thank you! I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: works fine with multiple monitors! for others in the same situation, I have everything in the Preferences/Input on. Namely "Grab keyboard and mouse input on mouse click", "Grab keyboard and mouse input on key press", "Automatically grab and ungrab the mouse" and "Hide cursor on grab". thanks again!

Comment: When I move the mouse on another monitor, then press a key, the key press goes to the guest as expected, but the mouse come back right in the middle of the screen on the guest. I would like multi-monitor VM to be as intuitive as any modern OS would be

Comment: Also, the keyboard isn't grabbed when pressing Ctrl+C (sending SIGINT to a terminal on linux guest)

Comment: @Bilow Regarding Ctrl+C: Are you talking about grab-on-keypress or using a dedicated USB keyboard to the VM?   If you're referring to grab-on-keypress, Ctrl+C doesn't work because it's the same shortcut key as Edit > Copy. Shortcut keys that correspond to menu items won't trigger automatic grab since otherwise grab-on-keypress would completely break keyboard accessibility for the UI.

Comment: @Bilow Regarding the mouse cursor: To clarify, where do you expect the guest mouse cursor to be?  Your definition of intuitive is not necessarily the same as everyone else's.  The guest mouse cursor can't be where the host's is (outside of the guest window).  The VM grabs both keyboard *and* mouse input or neither.  Grabbing just one or the other is also confusing. (BTW, it will happen whenever the mouse cursor is outside of the guest window and you grab.  It not related to multiple monitors or even grab-on-keypress.)

Comment: And if you don't intend to click on another window, then why do you want to move the mouse cursor out of the VM? - Have you never had more than one window open and the mouse just happens to not be overtop of the window you currently have active? 

an example would be having a word document open and a web browser, where you are tying in the word document and using the mouse to scroll up and down in the web browser. Right now I have two web browsers open and while I type this I am scrolling in the other web browser.

Comment: @Ravenous Using the mousewheel to scroll an unfocused window under the cursor is a fair point. (At the time that I wrote this answer, I don't think that Windows supported that, or it was a fairly new feature.) If you happen to be using a Windows guest, Unity mode might allow you type into a window from the guest while having the mouse over a window on the host.

Comment: Personally I would be happier if focus didn't leave the VM until mouse is clicked.  I never want my mouse to interact outside the VM until I've clicked.  I want to --->WITHOUT HOTKEYS<--- mouse out of the VM and click on something to leave the VM.  But I absolutely do not want my keyboard to stop working in the VM just because my mouse drifted out when I let go of it.  I swear it WAS working this way for the last two years but it recently started to ungrab the keyboard when the mouse drifts out...

Comment: @Grallen It has *never* worked that way in VMware products. If motion ungrab is enabled, then moving the mouse cursor out of the VM will automatically ungrab.  If motion ungrab is disabled, then you cannot move the mouse cursor out of the VM without explicitly ungrabbing with a hotkey.

Answer (score -1):

I know you're using VMWare Workstation, but, unfortunately, it seems like that software is limited in its ability to behave like any other window.  You're not insane for thinking this is the more intuitive behavior.

An alternative solution is to use another VM host, if you can.  Oracle VirtualBox, which I was using until recently, works the way you and I would expect.  OnMouseLeave does not divert input away from the VM until you click outside.

You also don't have to click an extra time to mouse into the VM again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1181149)

Comment: The original post was looking for a behavior that is standard for other VM host software as well as VNC software.  I don't feel that it's sufficient to just tell them to accept the limitations of this particular software as what SHOULD just be expected as if the constraints were anywhere other than in the design of VMWare.